# How to prevent simultaneous form submissions?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, api, form-submit

Currently we have an email address submit form that triggers an API call and pass pareters to an API endpoint.

Like this,

```
<form action="https://www.url.dom/api-endpoint-goes-here" method="post">
  <input type="text" id="name" name="name">
  <input type="email" id="email" name="email">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

**Issue:**
The api endpoint only supports one entry at a time
Some rear use-cases where a form is submitted by multiple customers online within 1 to 2 seconds where api endpoint receives entries together, the back-end data causes override issue where only  1 entry  receives.

**Question:**
Is there any way to prevent simultaneous multiple submissions at a time that triggers the api endpoint and add some kind of delay process where there is always a delay of a couple of seconds like  1 to 2 sec between each api call?

Comment: What prevents the API from handling multiple entries?

Comment: Hi @showdev it's a custom API that assigns a unique code to incoming email addresses submitted, in this case same code is being assigned to multiple email addresses when API gets multiple requests within 1 or 2 seconds. Adding a delay on front end seems to be the easiest fix.

Comment: I'm curious why the same code gets applied to multiple email addresses. Seems like a flaw or limitation of the API on which I'd want to focus. But I hear you about finding the easiest fix, too.

Comment: Hi @showdev yes I agree, seems to be a limitation of API endpoint but considering it is a custom API endpoint my thought is changing the functionally of a custom API is a bigger undertaking which eventually should be fixed (totally agree) but issue can be resolved by adding some delay / buffer time between each time API call is made. Hence, I'm trying to get advice on how to do it on front end easily.

Comment: Like Jorge Felico, I imagine some kind of buffer or queue system. For example, you could store the entries in a database and create a [cron job](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) that calls a server-side script to process one entry every 5 minutes (or whatever time increment you like). It's not strictly JavaScript, but would that be possible?

Comment: The difficulty with a JavaScript (client-side) solution is that browsers have no way to tell what other browsers are doing, unless that information is somehow tracked server-side.

Comment: Yes, agree may be there is another queue solution that be used? Just do you think I if it's right to think that controlling the traffic to API trigger is the right way to solve this issue? Any recommendations here?

Answer (score 0):

The best route for this would be to set up some sort of queuing system where you have a list of submissions and process them one by one on the backend, as opposed to sending the query straight to the final API endpoint.

You can use something like [Amazon SQS](https://aws.amazon.com/sqs/) to push and pull from the queue.

Comment: Hi Jorge, thank you for your recommendation. Yes I agree, that was my thought with some added buffer time or queue system where only one API call will happen at a time will resolve this issue. I have not heard of / worked with Amazon SOS and it looks like a service which probably needs to be integrated and involve a bigger undertaking, is there any alternative where a logic or some kind of loop system is added in the front end? May be via JavaScript / JS? Just thinking out loud...

Comment: Hi @Jorge Felico just following up if you have any additional recommendations?

Comment: As @showdev stated, since there's no way for browsers to know what each other are doing, I don't think there's a JS way of doing it, unless you had a NodeJS server somewhere where the initial request was going to.

Like others have stated, you will definitely need some sort of server-side solution to achieve what you are trying to do with a queuing system.

Comment: Hi @Jorge Felico thank you for your response. May be too basic question but is queuing system is needed / best practice for use-cases like this where API endpoint is being triggered / called on the website (where real-time events are being captured)? OR it is a back-end API endooint's job to handle the multiple requests by implementing it's own queuing process? Just trying to understand, is is better to implement the queuing process on the site that is triggering the API or optimize the API endpoint itself to be able to handle multiple requests?

Comment: Hi Jorge - just wanted to follow up...looking for some guidance here...